# DELETE multiple tables where at least one is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

<strike>I'm deleting certain rows from multiple tables like this:</strike>

I would like to clean up certain tables after an entry from the main table has been removed. I know the ID of that entry (which is the fid in all other tables) but not every table contains related data.

This is what I came up with:

```
DELETE a, b, c
   FROM  tableA AS a 
      LEFT JOIN tableB AS b 
         ON a.fid = b.fid
      LEFT JOIN tableC AS c 
         ON a.fid = c.fid 
      WHERE  a.fid = 123
```

This only works if tableA contains at least one row with a `fID` of `123`

How can I delete remove certain rows from `tableB` and `tableC` when `tableA` has no matching row?

Comment: Er, RIGHT JOIN - or swap the tables around?

Comment: I don't understand what you want because of the condition `a.fid = 123`.  If there are no rows in `tableA` that match, what do you want to delete.  You can clarify the question by providing sample data and identifying what you do want and do not want to delete.

Comment: I don't know if any table has a matching row. Maybe a, b or c can have an entry or not

Comment: Outer join.. Would it help?

Comment: What you would need, in theory, would be "FULL OUTER JOIN" but it doesn't exist in MySQL. So you'd have to imitate it by e.g. combining LEFT JOIN of your tables in different order.

Comment: So you want to delete all records from all the three tables where the fid is a given id. Why do you need to delete them in one query? Start a transaction, run delete for all tables separately, then commit the transaction.

Comment: @Pred correct, just curious how it would work in a single query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest approach is three delete statements:

```
delete tableA where fid = 123;
delete tableB where fid = 123;
delete tableC where fid = 123;
```

If you want to do this as one statement, use `left outer join` but start with the list of ids to delete:

```
delete a, b, c
   from (select 123 as fid
        ) todelete left outer join
        tableA a
        on todelete.fid = a.fid left outer join
        tableB b
        on todelete.fid = b.fid left outer join
        tableC c
        on todelete.fid = c.fid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested Query using + operator as in Oracle.
Check if it would help:

```
DELETE a, b, c
   FROM  tableA AS a , tableb as b, tableC as c
   and a.fid = b.fid(+)
   and a.fid = c.fid(+);
```